# what is the length of metadata byte of flv video file?

Tags: c#, metadata, flv

I am reading a live streaming flv stream by `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` like

```
Stream stream = responseObj.GetResponseStream();
while (read = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
```

I need to know what is the length of byte of metadata for this flv response.

Thanks in advance. It will be great help for me.